# Add $values to post_class()

Tags: posts, post-class

This must be pretty simple, but it is eluding me. I need to add several classes to `post_class()` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class

I can add one class in a page template, as below:

`post_class($even_odd);`

but I need to add several more, i.e. `$current_post` and `$current_in_total`

They won't `echo`, and they won't output this way: `post_class($current_post; $even_odd; $current_in_total;)`

I need to output these in a page template using `post_class()`, not add them via a hook in functions.php

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple [post classes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class) should be separated by a single space or should be in an array.

`post_class("$even_odd $current_post $current_in_total");`

Or

`post_class(array($even_odd, $current_post, $current_in_total));`

Comment: Ah, I was using single quotes. The first example works fine. Thanks!

Comment: Variables don't 'expand' inside single quotes